# Active User Tracking, PHP Sessions

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-like

Alright, I'm trying to work on a function for active user counting in an AJAX based application. I want to express the below SQL Query in correct syntax but I'm not sure how to write it. The desired SQL Query is below:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM active WHERE timestamp > time() - 1800
     AND nick=(a string that doesn't contain [AFK])
```

Now, I do understand that time() - 1800 can be assigned to a variable, but how is `timestamp > variable` and nick that doesn't contain a string written in SQL?

Comment: I'm not very good with SQL, but perhaps use, for the string that doesn't contain [AFK]: AND NOT LIKE "%[AFK]%"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM active WHERE timestamp > unix_timestamp() - 1800
     AND nick NOT LIKE '%[AFK]%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `time()` to refer to the current time? And can we assume `timestamp` to be of type `datetime`? Then this should work:

```
SELECT
    count(*)
FROM
    active
WHERE
    timestamp > NOW() - 1800
```

Comment: now() wouldn't work because we're looking for timestamps. Does the comment left on the question work for the AFK Checking?

Comment: Huh, NOW() is a synonym for CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), but I see that the accepted answer talks about *Unix* timestamps, which wasn't apparent to me. In any event, what you need is http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html .

Answer (score 0):

About the username, you should filter each variable before putting it into a sql query([SQL Injection](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=PRT&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&q=SQL+Injection&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=)).

```
$nick =  mysql_escape_string($nick);
```

and then in the sql query:

```
$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM `active` WHERE `timestamp` > (time() - 1800) AND `nick` = '{$nick}' AND `nick` NOT LIKE '%[AFK]%' LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: It is filtered, I only posted relevant code, and your nick= part of query doesn't filter only results without the [AFK] string.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM active 
WHERE timestamp > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1800 SECOND)
AND nick NOT LIKE '%[AFK]%'